# What is this style of isometric illustration called?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

What is the following style of illustration called?
I've searched with Isometric Illustration but there seem to be various types of it. Is there a specific name for this one?

[image: http://www.goodfromyou.co/you/2016/3/2/hot-property]

Answer (score -2):

isometric design/illustration is right you can also search for perspective illustrations

Comment: So they only call it isometric or perspective illustration right? I thought they have like a specific name for the style because I found some were made in 3D and some were flat isometric like this one. But thanks for the answer :)